# What do the different color bubbles in Tensorboard mean?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am using Tensorboard to find why my tensorflow model is not training properly.  The below graph shows three weights (W, W_1 and W_2).  W_1 and W_2 are initialized identically (as random_normal) with the exception of shape.  W_2 trains properly but W_1 does not train at all.  One is orange and the other is pink.  Does this suggest the problem and if so, can anyone tell me how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the code for the initialization of your weights and biases?

The color codes in tensorboard are a useful place to start (since no code snippets have been provided).

Note that W and W_1 have one color and W_2, B, B_1 and B_2 have another color. This means they have been initialized differently. This can explain why you get different results for W_2 and W, W_1.

A recommendation would be to go back to the initialization of all weights and spot the difference in initialization. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Tina_Iris W_1 and W_2 were initialized identically - they use the same initialization function, syntax (everything I can think of) with the exception of shape.  My question centers on what the colors mean since the colors of W_1 and W_2 are different and behave differently. I am hoping that the color legend for Tensorboard (if I could find one) would tell me something useful about how to debug.